# Connecting to sharepoint server error

Tags: sharepoint-addin, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, server

I am currently developing a sharepoint webpart and I need to be connected to our remote Sharepoint site for access to certain variables and functions

All is fine and well for some time, I would usually open visual studio and head to Tools -> Add sharepoint connection -> Specify sharepoint site/login to account

However, as of last night I am getting this error in the following picture

[image: Picture]

It was never a local server to begin with and I am not getting the option to connect to a remote sharepoint server

Thanks ahead of time!

Comment: Are your credentials expired? Did you check that?

Comment: As soon as I press "Add sharepoint connection" I immediately get the error and I am unable to enter my username and password

Answer (score 1):

To resolve the error make sure that the account being used to run Visual Studio is a db_owner on the SharePoint config and SharePoint admin databases.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up trying to repair my install of Sharepoint Foundation 2013. Did not work.

However I uninstalled Sharepoint Foundation and reinstalled it and my problem was fixed. Thanks for all the helps.